# turn on/to the right

Tags: prepositions

Suppose you are giving directions. Are the following all okay? If so, what's the difference?

> a. Take a turn to the right.

> b. Take a turn on the right.

> c. Make a turn to the right.

> d. Make a turn on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe "make" and "take" are identical here, so I'll just talk about a. and b.

Sentence a. is natural and just means "Turn right."

Sentence b. is less natural. It's not natural because it feels like parts of two different ideas were put together and a lot of words are missing. It probably means, "Turn right when you come to the place where you can turn right."

Comment: In the Longman Dictionary, I found, "Take the second turn on the left."

Comment: @Apollyon Yes, with "the" it's much more natural because it indicates a specified location, rather than an unspecified location, "***a** turn*".

Answer (score 4):

*Turn to the right* or simply *turn right*, meaning 'turn yourself to face what was your right side'. You could say *make a turn to the right.*

*Take the next turning on the right*, meaning 'go along the next path/street you come to on the right-hand side'

Comment: In British English, is "Take a turning on the right" correct?

Comment: Well, you wouldn't say that because it's too vague! You might say '_the_ turning' if there was only one.

Comment: The use of "turning" in that sentence would most certainly grab the attention of an American English speaker. "Take the next _turn_ to the right" or simply, "Take the next right" would be _much_ more common. The use of "turning" would instantly flag you as a non-native speaker.

Comment: @FreeMan - Not in Britain!

Comment: Hence my notation of _American_ English speaker. ;)